# How to draw a cross on Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have following task - I need to draw on Google Maps a cross with certain coordinates. I know how can I do it using ItemOverlay but I think that there is means without using a custom marker. I need simple black cross with my coordinates. Please, tell me, is it possible?

UPDATE: I don't want to use ItemOverlay because I need to make a custom drawable for it and I hope there is simple android internal elements for it.

Comment: Why don't you use `Overlay` class which is quite practical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but using `Overlays` seems to be the only way of drawing any line on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw an **ImageView** right over the google maps view (with absolute positioning using margins). But then you'd have to take care of coord conversion (and reacting to user scrolling, zooming the map) "by hand".

I think you could also use **SurfaceView** fully aligned to google maps view and draw your marker right on it.

But both solutions are pretty much overkill; you're better off using **ItemizedOverlay** unless you have a really good reason no to - in which case you might wanna add some info on what's the reason, maybe we'll find you a nice solution to that one :)